# Does 70% of our brains cells change every day? If yes, how significant is that?

Tags: neurology

Frederick Travis claims that 70% of our brain cells change every day (for example in [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dm5h1Z88lWQ) and in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlxGBZifk6k)). Considering that we've got a lot of brain cells, that 70% seems a lot as well.

If this is the case, what does that mean? What kind of changes are taking place? Perhaps the cells are not changing substantially? Maybe it's just proof of cells being active, but not proof of functional changes?

Comment: The claim is that *connections between brain cells* change  not brain cells. This claim is a lot more meaningful (although I'm still not sure what exactly this refers to, or how the number would be derived).

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics.SE! Are the 70% brain cells neurons or glia that you are referring to as changing? Hippocampus may be the only location in the brain where new cells are added throughout the lifetime of a person-http://www.brainfacts.org/about-neuroscience/ask-an-expert/articles/2012/are-you-born-with-all-your-brain-cells-or-do-you-grow-new-ones. The second part of the question may be more appropriate for http://biology.stackexchange.com/ and you can have a look at questions such as these http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/are-brain-cells-replaced-over-time for more data.